# Twitter icon has the wrong size

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As you can see, it should be bigger:

[image: twitter]

Comment: Most icons are the wrong size. Check anyone's user page. You'll notice a supersized icon.

Comment: Works on my machine?

Comment: Cache problem. Disregard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uploaded new icon to twitter. This should be going live per Core Dev team.